# Refresh Application Automatically When Data changed in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server and I have 3 Application servers. When a table in my database have changed I need to those application servers refresh there local cached data. I use a trigger to known change and send a message via Service broker queue. Then I create a stored procedure and assign it to activate stored procedure of my queue, In this stored procedure I receive message, but I don't know How should I call refresh method in my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar issue but this code resolved the issue :

```cs
public class QueryNotification
{
    public DataSet DataToWatch { get; set; }
    public SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public SqlCommand Command { get; set; }
    
    public string GetSQL()
    {
        return "SELECT * From YourTable";
    }
    
    public string GetConnection()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }
    
    public bool CanRequestNotifications()
    {
    
        try
        {
            var perm = new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            
            perm.Demand();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public void GetData()
    {
        DataToWatch.Clear();
        Command.Notification = null;
        var dependency = new SqlDependency(Command);
        dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnChange;
    
        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command))
        {
            adapter.Fill(DataToWatch, "YourTableName");
        }
    }
    
    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
    
        var i = (ISynchronizeInvoke)sender;
    
        if (i.InvokeRequired)
        {
    
            var tempDelegate = new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
    
            object[] args = { sender, e };
    
            i.BeginInvoke(tempDelegate, args);
    
            return;
        }
    
        var dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
    
        dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;
    
        GetData();
    }
    
}
```

**Update:**

Check for permission:

```cs
public bool CanRequestNotifications()
{
    try
    {
        var perm = new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
                    
        perm.Demand();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For Instance in your window load:

```cs
if (!_queryNotification.CanRequestNotifications())
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR:Cannot Connect To Database");
}
                
SqlDependency.Stop(_queryNotification.GetConnection());
SqlDependency.Start(_queryNotification.GetConnection());
    
if (_queryNotification.Connection == null)
{
    _queryNotification.Connection = new SqlConnection(_queryNotification.GetConnection());
}
    
if (_queryNotification.Command == null)
{
    _queryNotification.Command = new SqlCommand(_queryNotification.GetSQL(),
    _queryNotification.Connection);
}
if (_queryNotification.DataToWatch == null)
{
    _queryNotification.DataToWatch = new DataSet();
}

GetData();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at using the `SqlDependency` class.

More information at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to try solving the problem using TCP. Each app listens to a port and when another app updates the db it sends a message to the other apps saying they need to refresh.

Hope that was a good idea.